# ArgumentException was unhandled by user code: (System.ArguementException) occurred in System. Data.dll

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I was following an online Tutorial and i am very new to programming.

Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'server: xxxxx;database

Here's my Code:

```
Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection With {
    .ConnectionString = " Server= xxxx;Database = ist2gx;User= Ist2gx;Password=hnu91p;Trusted_Connection= True;ProviderName=SqlClient"
}
```

Please can someone help me out.

Comment: You might have a look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Ok I'll  check it out

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionString does not have a property named `ProviderName` in it. `ProviderName` is different from provider property in ConnectionStrings string.
You should change `ProviderName=SqlClient` with `Provider=sqloledb` for OLEDB connection strings.
Sql ConnectionString for a standard connection with username and password:

```
`"Data Source=ServerName; Initial Catalog=DataBaseName; User id=UserName; Password=Secret;Provider=sqloledb"`
```

Sql ConnectionString for a trusted connection:

```
`"Data Source=ServerName; Initial Catalog=DataBaseName; Integrated Security=SSPI;Provider=sqloledb"`
```

For more info take a look at [Connection Strings for different providers](http://www.devlist.com/ConnectionStringsPage.aspx) and [SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: `.ProvideName` is not a member of SqlConnection.

Comment: @Mary Right. I've missed that.